# Why is this page extra long in IE?

Tags: html, cross-browser

http://109.169.58.107/test/del.php

It's a normal length in all browsers except IE including IE9.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (line 136)

```
<div style="width: 700px; height: 700px">
```

Remove the height style.